# Should I load everything at once on app start ? (Best practice)

Tags: angular

I make an application with different pages to crud each main object I need.
The app has some big object using little one as properties.

Currently, I have to make a subscribe per littleObject composing a bigObject in the ngOnInit(), and I have to import each Subscription I need each time.

Is it possible (and should I) make it so app.component has all the subscription I'll need, and to call it when I need from other object ?

To sum it up :

1. Should I have 1 main component, app.component, with all the subcription in it
2. If 1 is valid, should I have my other component get to the value stored in app.component
3. If 2 is valid, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solution you can provide two services. You can check [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdfhmj) also.

**First one is httpRequest Service,**

```
  fakeReturn = 
  {
    data: {
        id: 1,
        name: "fuchsia rose",
        year: 2001,
        color: "#C74375",
        pantone_value: "17-2031"
    },
    data2: {
        id: 2,
        value: "fuchsia rose",
        placeholder: "fake test",
        text: "test",
    }
}
  getBigData(){
    return of(this.fakeReturn);
  }
```

The second one is data service.

```
  private bigData$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  private child1Data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  private child2Data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  bigData: Observable<any> = this.bigData$.asObservable();
  child1Data: Observable<any> = this.child1Data$.asObservable();
  child2Data: Observable<any> = this.child2Data$.asObservable();

  constructor(private requestService: HttpRequestService) {
    this.requestService.getBigData()
      .subscribe(bigData => {
        this.setBigData(bigData);
      });
  }

  setBigData(bigData: any) {
    if (bigData) {
      this.bigData$.next(bigData);
      this.child1Data$.next(bigData.data);
      this.child2Data$.next(bigData.data2);
    }
    else {
      this.bigData$.next(null);
      this.child1Data$.next(null);
      this.child2Data$.next(null);
    }
  }

  setChild1Data(childData: any) {
    let bigValue = this.bigData$.value || { data: null, data2: null };
    bigValue.data = childData;
    this.bigData$.next(bigValue);
    this.child1Data$.next(childData);
    console.log("CHILD1 DATA -> ", childData);
  }

  setChild2Data(childData: any) {
    let bigValue = this.bigData$.value || { data: null, data2: null };
    bigValue.data2 = childData;
    this.bigData$.next(bigValue);
    this.child2Data$.next(childData);
    console.log("CHILD2 DATA -> ", childData);
  }
```

and on any component

```
this.dataService.child1Data.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroySubject$))
.subscribe(child1 => {
  this.child1Data = child1;
  console.log("component child 1 ->", this.child1Data);
});

this.dataService.child2Data.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroySubject$))
.subscribe(child2 => {
  this.child2Data = child2;
  console.log("component child 2 ->", this.child2Data);
});

this.dataService.bigData.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroySubject$))
.subscribe(bigData => {
  this.bigData = bigData;
  console.log("component bigData ->", this.bigData);
});
```